# lowest possible complexity for multiplying 2 linked lists representing very large numbers?

Tags: list, complexity-theory, largenumber, multiplication

I have 2 linked lists representing very large numbers (that cannot be saved in anything else other than a linked list).
i have an Add method with the complexity of O(n).
i wanted to know if it is possible in any way to multiply the 2 numbers WITHOUT converting the whole list to a String/int/long (calculate ON the list if possible), and keep it on a complexity of O(n^2).

for now, no matter what i try i get to an O(n^3) complexity, and it isnt good enough.

thanks for all the help.

Comment: isn't that mainly a language agnostic question?  You might leave the java label off to attract the .NET and python and ... crowd. Also   checkout : http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you're right, ill take it off, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["long multiplication"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm) algorithm most westerners learn in school already gives you O(n²) complexity, so maybe you could explain what algorithm you are using.

There are algorithms with lower complexity: [Karatsuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), [Tom-Cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication), and  [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm). The last one has the lowest known complexity know to date, O(n log n log log n), but there may be even better algorithms yet to be discovered.